# What does the verbal phrase 'presented to' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, verbs, deverbal

In this following context, what does the verbal phrase 'presented to' mean?

Does it mean 'shown'?

How should I understand this clause 'that has ever been presented to this ego-centric world,'?

Context:

> One who aspires to become a Buddha is called a Bodhisatta, which,
> literally, means a wisdom-being. This Bodhisatta ideal is the most
> beautiful and the most refined course of life that has ever been
> **presented to** this ego-centric world, for what is nobler than a life of
> service and purity?

Source: P. 7

Buddhism in a Nutshell
BY NARADA THERA

Comment: Present here implies (I think)-to show...

Comment: "Does it mean 'shown'?" Yes. Is there a reason you think it would mean something else? If so, please specify that in your question.

Comment: You keep asking awkward questions about this text, which is really not suitable material for learning English *at all*, let alone *current* English. The cited example could well reflect a level of "anthropomorphism" in the writer's (or translator's) native language, but in "normal" English I'd expect something more like *This Bodhisatta ideal is the most beautiful and the most refined course of life that has ever **arisen in** this ego-centric world*. Well, just for that "presented" bit. The rest of the sentence is decidedly "flowery" language, best not imitated by learners anyway.

Comment: "presented to" isn't a phrase here. It's the past participle "presented" followed by the preposition "to". The word "presented" is part of the passive structure "*has ever been presented*" and "to" is part of the prepositional phrase, "*to this ego-centric world*".

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic question of word meanings. I don't even believe it should be described as a "verbal phrase" which makes the situation sound complicated. It's the standard verb "presented"  followed by a prepositional phrase. The meaning of "presented" is:

"To bring (someone) into the presence of (a person); to introduce formally. [from 14th c.]
to present an envoy to the king"
"(transitive) To put (something) forward in order for it to be seen; to show, exhibit. [from 14th c.]"
[wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/present#Verb)

Therefore it means "to introduce", "to show", "to exhibit", .